# Generating a no more records message

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So I have this script that when you press a button it loads more records so I want to add a message that will say that there is no more records once you can't load any more records so how can I do that?

Here's  my code

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

#load-more-button {
width: 100px;
margin: auto;
display: block;
}

.results-container {
width: 350px;
margin: auto;
}

</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){

/*<load more by pressing a button script>*/

//<settings define
var start = 0;
var limit = 10;
var reachedMax = false;
//

//Call the ajax request on page load
getData();
//

//load more records by pressing a button
$('#load-more-button').click(function(){
getData();
});
//

/*<function>*/
function getData() {
if (reachedMax)
return;

//settings variable
var settings = {
getData: 1,
start: start,
limit: limit
};
//

//result variable
var result= function(response) {
if (response == "reachedMax"){
reachedMax = true;
}
else {
start += limit;
$(".results-container").append(response);
}
}
//

//request
$.ajax({
url: 'data.php',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'text',
data: settings,
success: result 
});
}
/*</function>*/
/*</load more by pressing a button script>*/

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="results-container"></div>
<button id='load-more-button'>Load more</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**data.php**

```
<?php
$servername='localhost';
$username='x';
$password='1234';
$db_name= 'x';

$connect = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$db_name);

$start = $connect->real_escape_string($_POST['start']);
$limit = $connect->real_escape_string($_POST['limit']);

$query = "SELECT*FROM user_details LIMIT $start, $limit";

$result= $connect->query($query);

?>
<style>
#number{
background-color: gold;
color: black;
border-radius: 100%;
padding: 5px;
}

h2{
display: inline-block;
}

</style>

<?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>

<h2 id='number' ><?php echo $row['user_id']; ?></h2>
<h2><?php echo $row['username']; ?></h2>
<p><?php echo $row['password']; ?></p>

<?php } ?>
```

I googled around and I spent a week on this and I still can't figure this out.

Comment: It would probably be better to return a JSON array and do the formatting in the client. Then the client can simply check if the length of the array is 0, which means no more results.

Answer (score 0):

Check the number of rows returned in PHP:

```
$result= $connect->query($query);
if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
    echo "reachedMax";
    exit;
}
```

BTW, it makes no sense to escape `$start` and `$limit`, they're not strings. use `intval()` to force them to be numbers.

```
$start = intval($_POST['start']);
$limit = intval($_POST['limit']);
```

If you want to do it in Javascript instead of changing your PHP, you can simply check whether the result contains any `<h2>` tags. If there were no rows returned, the loop won't run and won't return any of those elements. So:

```
var result = function(response) {
  if (response.indexOf("<h2>") == -1) {
    reachedMax = true;
  } else {
    start += limit;
    $(".results-container").append(response);
  }
}
```

The best, most general way would be to redesign this so that the AJAX call returns JSON rather than HTML. Then you can just check the length of the JSON array.

Comment: I took your advice but when I reached the end of the records no message appear like same result as before.

Comment: Wait I think I made a mistake give me a moment.

Comment: Thanks it works but how can I do this in a jquery ajax way instead I'm trying to avoid using that in a php way for personal reasons which can cause conflicts on a new add on that i'm planing on adding later. Do you know how to do this in a ajax with jquery way?

Comment: Return JSON instead of HTML. BTW, your code appends a copy of the same `<style>` block every time you call it. That should just be in the original HTML, it shouldn't be in the AJAX.

Comment: Also, IDs are supposed to be unique, you shouldn't have `id="number"` in the loop. Use a class instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response barmar but it is giving me an error which is this Uncaught ReferenceError: responseindexOf is not defined.

Comment: And I'll consider your advice but what is responseindexOf referring to in your code example? That is how i'm getting that error.

Comment: Typo, it should be `response.indexOf`. Wasn't it obvious? Don't you know about the `indexOf` function for arrays and strings?